# How to do this expression of php explode in javascript?

Tags: javascript, explode

Hey guys just wondering how this php explode code can be written in javascript.

Taken from here: https://eval.in/82916 (full code)

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    list($a, $b) = explode(' ', $value);
    $arr1[] = $a;
    $arr2[] = $b;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a code conversion site. It is very easy to research available string methods in javascript. Question shows a complete lack of research effort

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @charlietfl been researching for 30mins-1hour, am new to coding so dont know much. I understand split but not in as much detail as being able to split each element in the array(if that makes sense).

Comment: Well if you knew about split() you shoud have shown what you tried with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from JavaScript 1.7, the following solution would be supported:

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
array.forEach(function(value) {
    [a, b] = value.split(' ');
    arr1.push(a);
    arr2.push(b);
});
```

However since that solution would only work on the newest of browser versions (also did not work for me on Chrome, on Firefox it did), I definitely do not recommend using it.
I'd suggest going with something like this instead:

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
array.forEach(function(value) {
    var splits = value.split(' ');
    arr1.push(splits[0]);
    arr2.push(splits[1]);
});
```

That should work for pretty much everyone.

Comment: Honestly thanks a million for that, there is no way I wouldve  been able to achieve that result just by myself, so your answer is greatly appreciated.